# data attribute of element showing undefined using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying to grab the data attribute of an element but somehow it says undefined.
here is my html code

```
 <div id="imageContainer">
    <img data-fullimageid="1" data-title="Cool Stuff" class="backgroundImages" src="images/galvanize/1.jpg" />
    <img data-fullimageid="2" data-title="Awesome" class="backgroundImages" src="images/galvanize/1336/dj.jpg" />
    <img data-fullimageid="3" data-title="Elite" class="backgroundImages" src="images/galvanize/3.jpg" />
</div>
```

And using Jquery to alert it

```
    var firstImageTite = $('.backgroundImages:first-child').data("data-title");
alert(firstImageTite);
```

**it says Undefined.
Please tell me where i am wrong, thanks.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
$('.backgroundImages:first-child').data("title");
```

instead of

```
$('.backgroundImages:first-child').data("data-title");
```

jquery `.data` caches the value of the data-* into the key with the name that appears after `data-`. So while using setter and getter of jquery data api, you just need to mention the attribute name (*without prefix*).

*Also do note that any changes you make using .data does not change the actual attribute value, so once modified with .data api retrieve it with .data api as well*

Answer (score 2):

**Replace**

```
.data("data-title");
```

**with**

```
.data("title");
```

**OR**

```
.attr("data-title");
```

Answer (score 1):

put title instead of data-title.

```
$(function(){
$('#titledata').text($('.backgroundImages:first-child').data('title'));
});
```

Running example is here

http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshmepco/ud6Ww/1/